# VBA User defined subroutine description

Tags: vba, subroutine

Do you know what is the limit of chars for the `Description` argument of the `Application.MacroOptions` method. There is no official info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.macrooptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this pretty quickly. I got an error once n passed 255.

```vb
Function TestMacro()
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Function
 

Sub AddUDFToCustomCategory()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 500
        Application.MacroOptions Macro:="TestMacro", Description:=String(n, "x")
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I asked this question as my description in the Macro dialog (opens after clicking Developer->Macros) has reached the limit and I am pretty sure that I did not used 255 characters there.